# Prove/ disprove: there exists a finite runtime algorithm s.t given a formula $\phi=\exists x_1...x_n \forall y_1 ... y_n A$ to check satisfiability

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

**Question:**

Prove/ disprove: there exists a finite runtime algorithm s.t given a formula $\phi=\exists x_1...x_n \forall y_1 ... y_n A$ that checks the satisfiability of $\phi$ when A is a formula with no quantifiers, function symbols or equality relation.

**My answer**
I believe this is false (after a week of believing that it's true). So now I want to make sure, how about this proof:

A reduction to Church's theorem:

Given a general formula A

Assume by contradiciton that such algorithm $Z$ exists.

$A$ is satisfiable $\iff A^\forall$ is satisfiable $\iff \exists x_1 ... x_n A ^\forall=\psi $ is satisfiable, (when the x's are new variables that didn't appear in $A$ before, I'm allowed to change the name of variables prior to this step if needed).

Now $Z(\psi)$ can solve the general satisfiability problem in contradiction with Church's theorem.

Comment: What is $A^\forall$ in your proposed solution? If $A$ is a general formula (with quantifiers), couldn't $\exists x_1,\dots,x_n\, A^\forall$ have further quantifiers inside the existential and universal blocks?

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Bernays-Schönfinkel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernays%E2%80%93Sch%C3%B6nfinkel_class). To decide whether your formula $\phi=\exists x_1...x_n \forall y_1 ... y_m A$ is satisfiabie, note that it is satisfiable iff it has a model with at most $n$ elements (because, as we have disallowed function symbols, we can discard elements other than the witnesses for the $x_i$ without invalidating $\phi$). It is a finite problem to decide whether $\phi$ has a model with at most $n$ elements.

[Your argument breaks down because $A$ is *not* an arbitrary formula here.]

Comment: Okay, so what you're saying is that every M that satisfies $\phi$ must have at most $n$ elements because all other elements of $D^M$ are not terms that can be placed in any $x_i$. So the algorithm will be to finitely iterate over the $\le n$ constant we do have?

Comment: Not quite. What I am saying is that any model contains a substructure comprising the witneesses to the $x_i$ which is also a model. So you only need to search for a model with $n$ elements. (By the way, you don't have to have the same number of $y_j$ as $x_i$.)